# Easiest ways to transform ParaView serial files in parallel ones

Tags: file, parallel-processing, visualization, vtk, paraview

I have a bunch of large serial VTK files. I gained acess to a cluster with ParaView in it and wanted to take advantage of its capabilities.

How can I turn them into parallel files? Do I have to re-write then?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by exploiting vtkXML**P**<...> writer/reader(s), where XML**P** denotes XMLParallel.

You can explore the VTK examples from the doxygen doc [here](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/c2_vtk_t_23.html).

You can get started by running the python `testParallelXMLWriters.py` example.

Basically, you open up your serial files with the serial XML reader e.g. vtkXMLStructuredGridReader for a Structured Grid based dataset, and then pipeline it to an instance of a vtkXML**P**StructuredGridWriter for writing them to split XML files.

Paraview then aggregates the parallel XML files internally for rending from computing nodes.